# Gradle multi module project upgrade to java 21 and spring boot 3.x.x module by module

Tags: gradle, multi-module, spring-boot-3, java-21

Is it possible to upgrade one module at a time in gradle multi module project to use new gradle that supports java 21 i.e. 8.5 or 8.6, upgrade this module to java 21 and finally to upgrade it to new version of spring boot 3?

At the moment we are having modules that have java 17, gradle 7.6 wrapper and Spring Boot 2.7.x.
Would like to release one by one module and not to do upgrade all 7 modules I have in this repo.
I am using IntelliJ and have setup it up so that gradle uses project SDK and wrapper.
Project setup:

```
project
│
├── module1
│   ├── code
│   └── gradle.build
│
├── module2
│   ├── code
│   └── gradle.build
│
├── module3
│   ├── code
│   └── gradle.build
│
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ...
│
├── gradle.settings
└── gradlew
```

Tried to find any resources on the net but could not find something that can help with this.